# How to hide a div with a cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys I am currently creating a newsletter popup. 
I'm wanting to hide the div after the close button is selected using a cookie. The code snippet I've taken does include some code to try and achieve this but doesn't seem to work for me. Anyone know a solution?

JS

```
var delay = 0; //in milliseconds

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    setTimeout(function(){
        showNewsletterPopup();
    }, delay);

    jQuery('.popup-close').click(function(){
        $('.newsletter-overlay').hide();
    });
});

function showNewsletterPopup(){
    jQuery('.newsletter-overlay').show();
}

function onLoad() {
    var showDiv;
    if(localStorage.getItem("showDiv") == null) {
        showDiv = true;
    }
    else {
        showDiv = localStorage.getItem("showDiv")
    }

    if (showDiv) {
         document.getElementById('newsletter-overlay').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('newsletter-overlay').hide();
    }
}

function onClose() {
    document.getElementById('newsletter-overlay').remove();
    localStorage.setItem("showDiv", false);
}
```

HTML

```
<div  class="newsletter-overlay">

 <div id="newsletter-popup">
   <a href="#" class="popup-close"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/static/TLTX.svg"></a>

  <div class="col1">
   <div class="newsletter-in">
     <h3>Take 10% off your first purchase</h3>
     <p class="modalp">Join our Tribe! Our mates get the best rates. Every $1 spent will earn you 1 point. Be the first to know about new arrivals. Receive 10% off your first order! See more on our <a href="https://ellazafran.com/tribe/">Tribe</a> page
     [wc_reg_form_bbloomer]
          </div>
      </div>
        </form>
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: And where is onLoad called? Why are you not just checking to see if it exists before you call showNewsletterPopup? (localstorage !== cookie)

Comment: I didn't write the JS, sorry! I wasn't too sure how to get it to function correctly. How would I go about either calling it first or check to see if it exists?

Comment: Don't copy/paste code without knowing what it is doing.

Comment: Trying to learn :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the provided code is a bit messy... there are some unused functions and a lot of noise. however, here is my proposal:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    const $newsletterPopup = $('#newsletter-popup');
    const $newsletterOverlay = $('.newsletter-overlay');
    const $popupCloseLink = $('.popup-close');

    let showDiv = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("showDiv"));

    if (showDiv === null) {
        showDiv = true;
    }

    if (showDiv) {
        $newsletterOverlay.show();
        $newsletterPopup.show();
    } else {
        $newsletterOverlay.hide();
        $newsletterPopup.hide();
    }

    $popupCloseLink.click(function() {
        $newsletterOverlay.hide();
        $newsletterPopup.hide();
        localStorage.setItem("showDiv", false);
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried it out but didn't seem to work. Here is the link with the mentioned proposal https://ellazafran.com/pop-up/

Comment: Doh!!! Yes, localstorage returns a string! so, you actually have to do `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("showDiv"))`... I will update my answer, could you check? :)

Comment: THANK YOU! So much!